# If I restore my PS3 will it sign my account out?

Tags: ps3

So my Skyrim isn't working and I restored the file system already but I do t have my psn account password so I don't want to do it it will sign me out

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer have access to the e-mail account that you created your PSN account with then you will need to contact Sony support so they can verify you are the owner and help you update your contact info and reset your password. Otherwise, just do a password reset and Sony will e-mail you instructions to reset the password (note it can take anywhere from a day to a week for the password change e-mail to show up... not kidding!).